# Upgrading Angular 5 to 6 app works in development mode after some changes but not working after building for production

Tags: angular

Basically I upgraded my application Angular 5 - Angular 6. I needed to upgrade few packages and changes few functions and now app is working fine without any problem when I use following command

```
ng serve
```

But when I build the application and host compiled application from dist folder, I get following error in console.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(i)[t -> t]:  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

Comment: I had the same error recently. Be sure to disable optimization so that you can see what Angular cannot resolve.

Comment: Please provide more data (the entire error in the stack trace). It may be an error in a dependency.

Comment: share the stack trace